# Gradle: any difference between task configuration approaches

Tags: gradle, groovy, task

Is there any difference between two following pieces of code? 
May be there is some difference about eager initialization of a task?

```
tasks.bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "some-name"
}
```

and

```
bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "some-code"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

They are the effectively the same just different syntax. Both cause the task to be *realized* or eager initialized. You can confirm this by simply running with debug output: `./gradlew -d`

You will see the following line logged:

> [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Realize task :bootJar' started

For the Groovy DSL, the Gradle team takes advantage of the [metaprogramming](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html) offered by the Groovy language to dynamically make tasks, extensions, properties, and more "magically" available.

So for this example:

```
tasks.bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "some-name"
}
```

`tasks` is of type [`TaskContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.html). If you were to examine all available methods and properties for `TaskContainer`, you will see that `bootJar` is not one of them. So Gradle hooks into the Groovy metaprogramming to search for *something* named `bootJar`. Since it's on the `TaskContainer` type, it can be assumed that `bootJar` is a task.

So if you were to desugar the DSL, the first example is effectively:

```
tasks.getByName("bootJar") {

}
```

Now for the second example:

```
bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "some-code"
}
```

The default scope or `this` in a Gradle build file is [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html). Again, just like before, if you were to examine all available methods and properties, you will not see `bootJar` as one of them.

Groovy's 'magic' is at play here, but this time around, Gradle will search (my understanding) practically everywhere because there is *a lot* more available on a `Project`.

```
project.extensions.named("bootJar") // exists?
project.hasProperty("bootJar") // exists?
project.tasks.getByName("bootJar") // found it!
```

---

To summarize, no there is no difference between the two since both cause the `bootJar` task to be realized. Use [task configuration avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) wherever possible to make your Gradle builds more efficient:

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

tasks.named("bootJar", BootJar) {
    
}
```